# PHP Date Format

Tags: php, date

I have this format :

```
Thu Feb 11 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

My Question :

How can i format this date, to this kind of format in PHP:

```
2010:01:01 00:00:00 (Datetime)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$date = new \DateTime('Thu Feb 11 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)');
$formatedDate = $date->format('Y:m:d H:i:s');
```

See https://3v4l.org/TfR85 and for more information on the datetime object http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

I must also point out that your initial string doesn't follow any proper format. CET or GMT... there is a big difference

Answer (score 1):

Using  `strtotime()`:

```
$s = strtotime("Thu Feb 11 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)");
$s = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$s);
echo $s; //2010-02-11 00:00:00
```